# Watcher Vue JS on window object

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I want to store some of the variables between components in global window object, so I do  `window.showFilters = !window.showFilters`

In the components, I am trying to use watcher on window object like

```
watch: {
    "window.showFilters": {
      handler: () => {
        console.log(window.showFilters);
      },
      deep: true
    }
  },
```

However, this doesn't work so I have to use Vuex which I would like to use only for business data rather just code variables.
Is there are a right way to watch for variables in the window object?

Comment: I think should do the emit/subscribe pattern with the event bus instead of watching for variable changes.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to use the Vuex store (which is the recommended way - and you can simply separate your business and application state in 2 different Vuex modules) then you are advised to store such variables in the root Vue instance (the one in your `main.js`)

The problem with global variables (a.k.a `window` properties) is that they are not reactive. You could try to use `this.$set(window, 'showFilters', true)` but this is ugly and might not work.

But even putting your variables inside the root Vue instance you still need to inform your components about the changed value - and you can do this by emitting events only (a watcher can only watch for changes inside the same component - not between components)

Answer (score -2):

I resolved like this:

```
mounted(){
  setInterval(()=>app.myownwatcher(), 100)
},
methods: {
  myownwatcher(){ 
    // do something with window.showFilters
  
  }
}
```

It does not the best way but work :/ When my app run, I create a interval who update my model